# Sending large data through python pipe between multiple processes

Tags: python, out-of-memory, multiprocessing, pipe

I have a python script that analyses large sql trace files.
To increase performance the processing is distributed to multiple processes.
During the initialisation, the input file is loaded into an array, then this array is splited in 4 parts (for 4 processes). Each of this parts is sent to a process using a pipe.

If the array part is larger than about 200MB (whole array about 800MB), I get an "Out of memory" exception.

The exception occurs after the send() method has been called with the following message:

> parent_conn.send(data) MemoryError: out of memory

Is there a way to increase the possible size of a pipe?

what i've done:

```
def main():

    for i in range(0, self.no_threads):
            data = AnalyserData(i, queries)     #queries is a large array that contains about 1mio. elements
            parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()                
            process = Process(target=self.init_process, args=(child_conn,))             
            process.start()             
            conns.append(parent_conn)
            parent_conn.send(data)          
            threads.append(process)             


    for i  in range(0, len(threads)):       
            res = conns[i].recv()
            res.not_supported_queries = json.loads(res.not_supported_queries)
            thread_results.append(res)  
            threads[i].join()

def init_process(self,conn):            
    data = conn.recv()
    #do some processing...      
    conn.send(result)
```

Comment: I would guess it is not the pipe itself but some other aspect of the program that is causing the problem.  Please create a simple test case that shows the problem

Comment: Although I can't answer your actual question, maybe it would be more sane to not pass the data at all, simply send the file name and 'read offset' to the processes then let them read the file and create the arrays themselves. It seems inefficient to pass so much data around with no need to in the first place.

Comment: Are you forking your process 4 times for the pipes? This  might cause oom if done after reading the data.

Comment: "If the array is larger than about 200MB" which array, the original or the 4 parts?  What make you think that "Out of memory" is concerned with the size of the pipe?  More likely it is the size of the array.  Pipe size limits are implementation specific, on Linux there is a limit called PIPE_BUF (not Python specific) but you do not get those symptoms by exceeding it.

Comment: I can send 1GB on my machine (max process memory ~2GB). See [`multiprocessing-send-large-data-via-pipe.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/9334570) Could you provide a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your issue?

Comment: your code example is neither complete nor minimal. Look at for the valid example: [`multiprocessing-send-large-data-via-pipe.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/9334570). Do you get `MemoryError` if you run it? You could change the sent size if needed.

Comment: Yes, it causes out of memory